# Use of coalescing operator in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to format elements of array  that can contains multiple types :

```
interface OptionType {
  value: string | number | boolean
  label?: string | number | boolean
}
const inputArray : Array<number | string | boolean | OptionType> = [1, 2, { value: 3, label:'test' }]
```

I need all elements of my new array to be of type OptionType, so I used this :

```
const formattedArray = inputArray.map((option)=>({
  value : option.value ?? option,
  label: option.label ?? option.value?? option
}))
```

However, I keep getting  Typescript errors mentioning for example that "Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string'" and I know, that's why I'm using the Null Coalescing Operator for this.

I tried to use a basic check before like :

```
 if (typeof option === 'string' || typeof option === 'number' || typeof option === 'boolean')
```

and it works, but I'm basically losing the utility of the ?? operator.

Am I missing something or is it just the normal operation of Typescript ?

Comment: Typed out an answer but question got closed before it could post it, look at this page in the typescript docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html and the user-defined type guards section. Something like this would work. value : (option as OptionType).value ?? option,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question: this is currently a limitation of TypeScript. See this GitHub issue to read more about related discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1260

Here is a refactor of your example which will satisfy the compiler:

```ts
type BNS = boolean | number | string;

interface OptionType {
  value: BNS;
  label?: BNS;
}

const inputArray : Array<BNS | OptionType> = [1, 2, { value: 3, label:'test' }];

const formattedArray = inputArray.map(option => ({
  value : typeof option === 'object' ? option.value : option,
  label: typeof option === 'object' ? option.label ?? option.value : option,
}));
```